# Updating TextView in an Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Hey, I would like to get a hint in the right path of how to update the `TextView` in a `Activity`.

The situation is a current `Activity1` computes a given task and the result is supposed to be displayed in the `Activity2` while the user clicks on it. And when the user goes back to `Activity1` computes and then clicks, the result should be updated.

But instead the result comes out to be a previous value.

Comment: are you passing data as Extras?

Comment: just create a singleton object in Application class to make its data accessible between activities

Comment: you can use startactivityforresult if you want to pass data to previous activity, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Answer (score 2):

You have to maintain your data in **public variables** or **sharedpreferences**. Once you the activity is resumed you can get the value from the public variable or from sharedpreferences and then you can update textview.

Note:
 Read about [activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) that will help you to finish that.

Comment: This answer works, but you might want to show an example of how to do this, as you don't want to update the TextView with non-existent data the first time the Activity is launched.

Comment: Here is a simple sample http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Answer (score 1):

You can pass/get values by using bundles, sharedpreferences, or using static variables *which are not effective* because they are temporary.

Edit (You asked to maintain on back as well so giving example for shared preference):

This is your **SharedPreferences** class, which is static so you can reach from every activity.

```
public class SharedPref {

    public static void setDefaults(String key, String value, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static String getDefaults(String key, Context context) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        return preferences.getString(key, null);
    }

}
```

This is how you are going to set and get your data in/from the SharedPreferences

**Set:**

```
SharedPref.setDefaults("your_tag", "your_string_you_want_to_put", context);
```

**Get:**

```
SharedPref.getDefaults("your_tag", getApplicationContext())
```

So, you can set it in to your textview like this (you should consider doing a null check or try/catch block as well):

```
tv.setText(SharedPref.getDefaults("your_tag", getApplicationContext()));
```

(Will keep this in case it is needed but this is a one-way method)

Here is a bundle example of how you can achieve:

In your Activity1:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
        i.putExtra("string_tag", "string_value");
        startActivity(i);
```

In your Activity2:

```
      TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourView);
      tv.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("string_tag"));
```

Comment: author also needs to send data from activity2 back to activity1 when activity2 is closed.

Comment: sorry my bad, updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can also send your value in an Intent like this:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.whatever);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and receive it:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: Yes, its the basic step of passing through intent but the problem persist as the values are not updating.

Comment: @JaneWi.S check my answer please. It will persist till the application is uninstalled or cache is cleared manually.

Answer (score 0):

I do not share the thoughts on the previous poster. I would've done this:

Start Activity with an expected result:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putIntExtra("intToPass", 5);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

From SecondActivity pass the result back to Activity 1 on finish:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
 // Prepare data intent 
Intent data = new Intent();
data.putExtra("returnValue", returnValue);
// Activity finished ok, return the data
setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
super.finish();
```

Back in first Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (data.hasExtra("returnValue")) {
      Toast.makeText(this, data.getExtras().getString("returnValue"),
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Do something with your precious return value ;)
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to save it for later use, then use sharedpreferences

Edit: REQUEST_CODE & RESULT_OK are your own defined ints